# Java JAX-WS web-service client: how log request & response xml?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I created an implementation of `LoggingHandler` that implements `SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>`

It should log whenever `handleMessage` triggers (and it is never called in my case)

```
MyService service = new MyService();
MyServicePort port = service.getPortType();
```

now I try this:

```
BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider)port;
bindingProvider.getBinding().getHandlerChain().add(new LoggingHandler());
```

I do not see any request / response xml though.

Can you suggest any solution? Maybe there's another way to see output and request XML?

Answer (score 27):

It starts working if you use this method:

```
binding.setHandlerChain(handlerList);
```

So, first initialize this list with

```
binding.getHandlerChain();
```

then add your element to the list and after all

```
setHandlerChain();
```

Answer (score 3):

you can add a logger in you log4j.xml file :

```
<!-- Log WebService's inputs and outputs -->
<logger name="org.apache.cxf.interceptor">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="[YOUR_LOGGER]" />
</logger>
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is wondering the 'why' of @EugeneP excellent answer.

In the Interface javax.xml.ws.Binding, there is the following comment.

```
/**
 * Gets a copy of the handler chain for a protocol binding instance.
 * If the returned chain is modified a call to 
 <code>setHandlerChain</code>
 * is required to configure the binding instance with the new chain.
 *
 *  @return java.util.List&lt;Handler> Handler chain
 */
 public java.util.List<javax.xml.ws.handler.Handler> getHandlerChain();
```

So the getHandlerChain() method returns a copy of the List not the list itself. So you have to use setHandlerChain to update the actual List.