# Trace SOAP request/responses with JAX-WS on the client side

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I'm using JAX-WS reference implementation (2.1.7) and I want to trace SOAP request/responses on the **client side**. Actually, what I need is to examine some Http headers when I receive the response.

Following these previous questions ( [Tracing XML request/responses with JAX-WS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945618/tracing-xml-request-responses-with-jax-ws) and [Java JAX-WS web-service client: how log request & response xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808544/java-jax-ws-web-service-client-how-log-request-response-xml/2808663#2808663) ), I've created my own handler to log when I send a request and receive a response:

```
public class SHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>
{

  private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SHandler.class);

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public Set<QName> getHeaders()
  {    
    log.debug(">>>>>>>>>>> GetHeaders");
    return null;    
  }

  @Override
  public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext soapMessageContext)
  {
    log.debug(">>>>>>>>>>> HandleMessage");
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext soapMessageContext)
  {
    log.debug(">>>>>>>>>>> HandleFault");
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public void close(MessageContext messageContext)
  {
    log.debug(">>>>>>>>>>> Close");    
  }
}
```

and I add the handler to the handler chain during the service initialisation:

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "MyService", targetNamespace = "http://www.whatever.com/", wsdlLocation = "file:/path/to/wsdl")
public class MyService extends Service
{

    public MyService(URL wsdlLocation) {
        super(...);
        initializeBinding();
    }

    @WebEndpoint(name = "MyOperation")
    public MyPort getMyPort() {
        return super.getPort(new QName("http://www.whatever.com/", "MyPort"), MyPort.class);
    }

    private void initializeBinding() {        
        MyPort port = getMyPort();
        BindingProvider bindingProvider = ((BindingProvider) port);
        List handlerChain = bindingProvider.getBinding().getHandlerChain();
        handlerChain.add(new SHandler());
        bindingProvider.getBinding().setHandlerChain(handlerChain);        
    }

    ...

}
```

The problem is that this doesn't work at all on the client side. I don't see any logs and my handler is never executed when I send a request and receive a response.

Notice that there is no specific WSDL related to this issue because I work on an MDA platform that generates client/server artifacts from any WSDL. In addition, I cannot do this at configuration level as all is generated, so I can only do it programmatically (I've been googling this and all the solutions that I find are either the one in the original post or using the handler-chain.xml configuration file).

Am I missing something? Is there any other way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use `@HandlerChain(file = "....")` annotation?

From my pov, you can not mix constructor- and annotation-based configurations as on-deploy webservice initialization and creating new instance of your service class are performed in absolutely different contexts.

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to mention in my question that I already checked this solution but still needs a reference to an XML.

Comment: BTW, I think that you're right about doing that in the constructor. Having again a look to HandlerChain I've found this: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/amsurana/entry/jax_ws_handlers_part_3_of_3
It seems like is possible to do it using a HandlerResolver. I'll try that tomorrow.

Comment: Right, you could try HandlerResolver interface in a way similar to http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2007/jw-02-handler.html?page=3

Answer (score 23):

If you only want to look at the SOAP messages run with

```
-Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true
```

VM argument.

Comment: I'm already using that SP to dump the request and responses on the log, but what I need is to perform some actions depending on the message, headers, etc. For example, if I receive a response that is a 500 (Internal Server Error) throw an exception. My handler is just an example.

Comment: To my understanding this always go to System.out (or .err).  Not to a log.

Comment: This seems to have no effect for me. I guess the right flag must vary depending on which version you're using (and I have no idea which one I'm using.)

Comment: As of Java 1.7, this seems to have changed. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18354201/jax-ws-http-logging-in-java-1-7

Answer (score 1):

there are 2 tools that you can use to help with this:

- [soapui](http://www.soapui.org/)
- [Eclipse tcp/ip monitor](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.wsi.ui.doc.user/tasks/tmonitor.html)

Both tools offer a proxy mode, which intercepts, logs and forwards requests and responses.

Comment: Well, as I said I need to perform some actions in the application itself depending on the response, therefore I can't use external tools.