# JAX-WS HTTP logging in Java 1.7

Tags: java, jax-ws, java-7

I am using JAX-WS as a client.  I used to use the following system property to log all HTTP requests & responses for debugging:

```
com.sun.xml.ws.transport.local.HTTPTransportPipe.dump=true
```

However, since upgrading to Java 1.7 and using the built-in JAX-WS (instead of the external libraries) this functionality has stopped working.

I have done a lot of searching to find what the equivalent properly is in 1.7 but have had no luck.  Does anybody know how to log the output?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true`

EDIT:

Ok, try `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true`

Or in your application:

`HttpTransportPipe.dump = true;`

From HttpTransportPipe.java:

```
   public static boolean dump;

    static {
        boolean b;
        try {
            b = Boolean.getBoolean(HttpTransportPipe.class.getName()+".dump");
        } catch( Throwable t ) {
            b = false;
        }
        dump = b;
    }
```

Comment: Hmm...Which version of Java 7 do you have?

Comment: This one worked! com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump...Thank you very much! (where did you find the information by the way?)  Version: jdk1.7.0_25

Comment: In the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-rt/2.1.7/com/sun/xml/ws/transport/http/client/HttpTransportPipe.java) itself.  I'll add the relevant bit to the answer.

Comment: Yes, the name of the property will depend on if you use the standalone JAX-WS RI or the one that is now bundled in the JDK (since v6).