# How to log SOAP messages which are sent by Metro stack

Tags: web-services, logging, client, java-metro-framework

I'm trying to log my messages which are sent using a Metro stack into console. 
Could not find any way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Message logging to stdout (valid for METRO **only**!):

**On the client**

**Java 5**: Set system property

```
-Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true
```

**Java 6**: Set system property

```
-Dcom.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true
```

**On the server side**

Set system property

```
-Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump=true
```

Comment: -Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true
is a saver for those needing to dump messages on the client side.

Comment: People say that package is slightly different from java 1.6, namely: `-Dcom.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true` (note additional `internal` after `xml`). And I confirm that it's true.

Answer (score 2):

Here everything is explained:

https://metro.java.net/2.0/guide/Logging.html

The following [options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16338394/381083) enable logging of all communication to the console (technically, you only need one of these, but that depends on the libraries you use, so setting all four is safer option).

```
-Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true
-Dcom.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true
-Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump=true
-Dcom.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't mention the language but assuming Java, could you not just use something like Log4J e.g.

```
service = new Service();
port = service.getXxxPort();
result = port.doXxx(data);

Log.info("Result is " + result.getResult().toString());
```

where getResult is just a method on the return object.

Comment: This one is performed after XML parsing. If you get broken XML or non SOAP/XSD valid XML - you don't have a change to call `toString()` because if fails earlier...