# Tracing XML request/responses with JAX-WS when error occurs

Tags: java, jax-ws

I want to log raw soap post requests if there are any errors , I am using JAX-WS. Any help will be appreciated.

Is there an easy way (aka: not using a proxy) to get access to the raw request/response XML for a webservice published with JAX-WS reference implementation (the one included in JDK 1.5 and better) only when exception occurs in response? I want to log raw SOAP reuest so that I can test it thorugh any webservice client at a later stage

Answer (score 36):

Use

`com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true`

and

`com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump=true`

instead (note the "internal" in the package name), this did the trick for me.

Cheers,
Torsten

Comment: changed catalina.sh file , included 'internal' but still cant see any changes in logs/catalina.yyyy-MM-dd.log files

Comment: .internal. is required when you are using the JAX WS version contained in the JRE, whereas the non ".internal." version is used, when you are explicitly using a JAX WS library

Comment: how to add timestamp, at what time a particular request reached to server and at what time server responded back ?

Answer (score 31):

Just thought I would mention this:

### The question when to use the property name with the `internal` in it and when not ?

If you read the [Metro Guide](https://javaee.github.io/metro/doc/user-guide/ch02.html#dumping-soap-messages-on-client) it will tell you to use:

on client:

```
com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true
```

on server:

```
com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump=true
```

However: It seems to me that when JAX-WS RI library got included as standard with the JDK (this was with Java 6) then Sun had to rename the property name to include 'internal'. So if you are using JAX-WS RI as it comes bundled with the JDK, then you *must* be sure to add the `internal` to the property name. Otherwise it will not work. In other words you need to use:

on client:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true
```

on server:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump=true
```

On the other hand if you are using a standalone version of JAX-WS RI (or of Metro as a whole) then I would guess you should use the property name *without* the `internal`.

I'll be glad if someone has inside knowledge on this and can say if this is true or not.

Answer (score 10):

It is OK to go with system properties (here is Gradle DSL for `test` task):

```
systemProperty "com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true"
systemProperty "com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true"
systemProperty "com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump", "true"
systemProperty "com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump", "true"
systemProperty "com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dumpTreshold", "99999"
systemProperty "com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dumpTreshold", "99999"
```

but those settings are global and may have high volume to enable them on PROD... It is not fun to add filters to your logging framework bound to business logic if you want to reduce volume of XML logging.

Details on capturing req/rsp bodies in WS handlers are in my answer [How can I pass data back from a SOAP handler to a webservice client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013476/how-can-i-pass-data-back-from-a-soap-handler-to-a-webservice-client/)

Here is an important part:

```
public class MsgLogger implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

    public static String REQEST_BODY = "com.evil.request";
    public static String RESPONSE_BODY = "com.evil.response";

    @Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        SOAPMessage msg = context.getMessage();
        Boolean beforeRequest = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(32_000);
            context.getMessage().writeTo(baos);
            String key = beforeRequest ? REQEST_BODY : RESPONSE_BODY;
            context.put(key, baos.toString("UTF-8"));
            context.setScope(key, MessageContext.Scope.APPLICATION);
        } catch (SOAPException | IOException e) { }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        return handleMessage(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void close(MessageContext context) { }
}
```

To register handler and use preserved properties:

```
BindingProvider provider = (BindingProvider) port;
List<Handler> handlerChain = provider.getBinding().getHandlerChain();
handlerChain.add(new MsgLogger());
provider.getBinding().setHandlerChain(handlerChain);

Req req = ...;
Rsp rsp = port.serviceCall(req); // call WS Port

// Access saved message bodies:
Map<String, Object> responseContext = provider.getResponseContext();
String reqBody = (String) responseContext.get(MsgLogger.REQEST_BODY);
String rspBody = (String) responseContext.get(MsgLogger.RESPONSE_BODY);
```

With this solution (it is only the skeleton, proper error handling / edge cases is up to you) you decide to log later when you've got response.

Comment: This answer is based on *The Java API for XML-Based Web Services (JAX-WS) 2.3* spec so should work for any JAX WS implementation.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Torsten's answer

> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true

Make sure that you set this before instantiating the WebServiceClient object (the one that extends Service)

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you might want to try is using one, or both, of the following system properties:

Client:

```
com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true
```

Server:

```
com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump=true
```

Comment: I added above properties in my catalina.properties file in my tomcat server, but cant see any logs updated, please advise

Comment: added to my catalina.sh on JAVA_OPTS but cant see any changes

Comment: Don't change catalina.properties. How are you setting `JAVA_OPTS`? The logging should be output via `System.out`.

Comment: Following is the JAVA_OPTS line in my catalina.sh file JAVA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.disableCaptureStackTrace = false -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump = true -Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump = true"

Comment: ...and nothing's showing up in logs/catalina.out? I suppose it would be good to know what JDK and Tomcat versions you're using...

Comment: TOMCAT 6.0.24 , jdk 1.6.0_18, cant see any changes in logs/catalina.yyyy-MM-dd.log files

Comment: set NO_SOAP_STACKTRACE=-Dcom.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.disableCaptureStackTrace=false
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %NO_SOAP_STACKTRACE%
echo NO_SOAP_STACKTRACE
This works, just (I'm editing the bat version of catalina) be sure to REMOVE every space (the text you showed us contains a space before the "=" char and one after)

Answer (score 2):

If you working with Jboss 6.1  and you want to print the logs for the JAX-WS generated classes request to the SOAP web service, 
open the file `/home/oracle/jboss-eap-6.1/bin/standalone.sh`
**note**: please go where you have installed jboss

You will find something like this

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=$DEBUG_PORT,server=y,suspend=n"
```

Change it to the one shown below

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=$DEBUG_PORT,server=y,suspend=n"
```

Also make sure you enable debug

```
DEBUG_MODE=true
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you need is an handler, see:
http://jax-ws.java.net/articles/handlers_introduction.html

With handler you can intercept web service call, and have access to all the SOAP message.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
-Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true
```