# SOAP client using WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I am writing SOAP client using WSDL. I have similar code in PHP, which works fine. However, I have some problems in Java. Here is my code snippet:

Where should I define the path to my local WSDL file?

Any idea is welcome.

```
try 
{
 SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
 SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

 SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(mySampleQuery(), 
                     "https://www.webpagename.com");

 // Process the SOAP Response
 printSOAPResponse(soapResponse);

 soapConnection.close();
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
 System.err.println("Error occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server");
 e.printStackTrace();
}

private static SOAPMessage queryFlightsByAerodrome() throws Exception
{     
 MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL);
 SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
 SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

 String serverURI = "localfolder/wsdlfilename.wsdl";

 // SOAP Envelope
 SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
 envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("mydata", serverURI);

 // SOAP Body
 SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
 SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("mySampleRequest", "mydata");

 SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("userId");
 soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("testuser");

 //...here I create soapBodyElem1 

 MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();

 headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI + "queryTestData");

 System.out.println("Content description: "+soapMessage.getContentDescription());
 soapMessage.saveChanges();

 /* Print the request message */
 System.out.print("Request SOAP Message:");
 soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
 System.out.println();

 return soapMessage;
}
```

After running this code I get the following error at line `SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(mySampleQuery(),"https://www.webpagename.com")`:

> Nov 03, 2014 4:18:27 PM
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl
>   identifyContentType SEVERE: SAAJ0537: Invalid Content-Type. Could be
>   an error message instead of a SOAP message Error occurred while
>   sending SOAP Request to Server
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl:
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid
>   Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP
>   response?     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.aslogic.isagent.MyAgent.main(MyAgent.java:46)
>   Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl:
>   Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a
>   SOAP response?    at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.identifyContentType(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(Unknown
>   Source)

Comment: are you sure your service url is correct? check with browser what its returning

Comment: @JIV: As I mentioned, I have similar code in PHP and it works fine. So, it means that service url is correct. However, in PHP I define the path to WSDL file and certificate file. I don't know how to do this in Java.

Comment: actually i don't think you building request correctly, maybe you should look on wsdl2java and try invoking client stub which is generated from wsdl, would be much easier for you

Comment: The strange thing is that System.out.println("Content description: "+soapMessage.getContentDescription()); returns NULL. May this be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

> > Invalid Content-Type. Could be an error message instead of a SOAP message

That's your first clue right there.

> > Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response

That's another clue. Putting it all together:

1. Your client is connecting to the service
2. The service is returning a non-SOAP response payload (it's returning HTML instead), hence the reason why SAAJ is choking on it.

Typically, a webservice will return HTML when it's responding with a standard JavaEE container-generated error page, as against the expected SOAP response. The question now is: *What is the error response that's being returned?* Talk to your service provider for feedback on what you're doing wrong. Also, look into logging everything that hits your client somehow

**Related**

- [Tracing XML request/responses with JAX-WS when error occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350476/tracing-xml-request-responses-with-jax-ws-when-error-occurs)