# How to trace SOAP requests that are being sent by webServiceTemplate

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, soap, tcp

I know it is possible to use Eclipse TCP/IP monitoring to trace SOAP messages. I tried that but it is not able to monitor my localhost. TCP/IP does not show the localhost in its console.

I can access the application through `http://localhost:8080/MyApp/`
In TCP/IP configuration I have following

```
Local monitoring port 9090 (a random port that I have chosen)
Host name: localhost
Port: 8080
Type: TCP/IP
Timeout:0
```

Is there any way to solve the issue with TCP/IP or find any alternative software?

Comment: set trace level logging for `org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing`.

Comment: I would go with Wireshark as it's an absolutely incredible tool to debug SOAP. You capture packets, type `http` into filter field to only show http requests/responses(you can specify src or dst and zillion of options) - right click on the list item -> 'Follow TCP Stream'. Or use one of the plugins.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) is one of the most comprehensive software for this (but its a little involved)

I have used, Fiddler and Charlesproxy, for the same - WebSvcs, Rest, SOAP (after having failed miserably in Eclipse tools). Both of them, are much superior to eclipse and very easy to use.

Here is the way you setup fiddler-

1. Download and start fiddler.
2. Add following VM Options in Eclipse preferences

   `DproxySet=true -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8888`
3. Optionally, you may also setup programatically

   `System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
   System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
   System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8888");
   System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8888");`
4. Restart your application.(I never needed to restart eclipse itself, but eclipse, sometime has a mind of its own)

Thats it, this is the most common and basic setup, useful for 90% of usecases, I have dealt with.
Note: Fiddler listens by default on 8888 port.

There is further setup, if your server uses SSL/certs.
Here is the link to full [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureFiddler).

Note: There is much content, even on stackoverflow on these setup, should you get stuck.

Also, Charlesproxy is also really good, but I have personally used fiddler mostly for Webservice client development.

Comment: I used wireshark but I was overwhelmed with number of HTTP messages that it showed.

Comment: I know,  that's why I don't recommend that as a first choice. But it is extremely powerful,  and once you get a hang of it,  you probably don't need any other tool. Did you try fiddler yet?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps instead of using the Eclipse TCP/IP monitoring you would prefer to enable the built in Spring logging? In that case you can enable logging on the `DEBUG` or `TRACE` level for

- `org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing` if you want to log on the client side
- `org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing` if you want to log on the server level

On the `DEBUG` level, only the payload root element is logged; on the `TRACE` level, the entire message content. See [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/common.html#logging) for details and a Log4J configuration sample.

Alternatively, you may configure a `PayloadLoggingInterceptor` or `SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor`. In `beans.xml` you can do that like this:

```
<sws:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadLoggingInterceptor"/>
</sws:interceptors>
```

More on that solution [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/server.html#server-endpoint-interceptor) (section 5.5.2.1)

Note that Spring uses Commons-Logging facade for logging, so you need an actual logging framework to see the logs, eg. Log4J.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to log SOAP message from the client side by enabling the following system properties:

```
System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true");
System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true");
System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump", "true");
System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump", "true");
```

Reference:

[Tracing XML request/responses with JAX-WS when error occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350476/tracing-xml-request-responses-with-jax-ws-when-error-occurs)

Answer (score 1):

You can use wireshark with loopback enabled and add http as a filter. Which will serve your purpose