# How to add soap header in java

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, ws-security, soapheader

i have a NO-.net webservice from oracle
To access i need to add the soap header. How can i add the soap header in java?

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new ProxyAuthenticator("username", "password"));
                System.getProperties().put("proxySet", "true");
                System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "IP");
                System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "port");




                proxy = new RegPresMed_Service(new URL("webservice")).getRegPresMed();
                ((BindingProvider) proxy).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "realwebservice");
                ((BindingProvider) proxy).getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.ws.request.timeout", new Integer(60000));
                ((BindingProvider) proxy).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "webserviceUsername");
                ((BindingProvider) proxy).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "webservicePassword");
```

is this necessary?

```
 ((BindingProvider) proxy).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "webserviceUsername");
                    ((BindingProvider) proxy).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "webservicePassword");
```

my soap header is like this:

```
<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1"
xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-6"
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password
Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce
EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">randomnaumber==</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created>dateCreated</wsu:Created>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
```

Answer (score 4):

I struggled to get this working. That's why I'll add a complete solution here:

My objective is to add this header to the SOAP envelope:

```
   <soapenv:Header>
      <urn:OTAuthentication>
         <urn:AuthenticationToken>TOKEN</urn:AuthenticationToken>
      </urn:OTAuthentication>
   </soapenv:Header>
```

1. First create a `SOAPHeaderHandler` class.

   ```
   import java.util.Set;
   import java.util.TreeSet;

   import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
   import javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement;
   import javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope;
   import javax.xml.soap.SOAPFactory;
   import javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeader;
   import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;
   import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler;
   import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext;

   public class SOAPHeaderHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

       private final String authenticatedToken;

       public SOAPHeaderHandler(String authenticatedToken) {
           this.authenticatedToken = authenticatedToken;
       }

       public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
           Boolean outboundProperty =
                   (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
           if (outboundProperty.booleanValue()) {
               try {
                   SOAPEnvelope envelope = context.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
                   SOAPFactory factory = SOAPFactory.newInstance();
                   String prefix = "urn";
                   String uri = "urn:api.ecm.opentext.com";
                   SOAPElement securityElem =
                           factory.createElement("OTAuthentication", prefix, uri);
                   SOAPElement tokenElem =
                           factory.createElement("AuthenticationToken", prefix, uri);
                   tokenElem.addTextNode(authenticatedToken);
                   securityElem.addChildElement(tokenElem);
                   SOAPHeader header = envelope.addHeader();
                   header.addChildElement(securityElem);
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           } else {
               // inbound
           }
           return true;
       }

       public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
           return new TreeSet();
       }

       public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
           return false;
       }

       public void close(MessageContext context) {
           //
       }
   }
   ```

   2. Add the handler to the proxy. Note that according javax.xml.ws.Binding's documentation: "If the returned chain is modified a call to `setHandlerChain` is required to configure the binding instance with the new chain."

   ```
   Authentication_Service authentication_Service = new Authentication_Service();
   ```

   Authentication basicHttpBindingAuthentication = authentication_Service.getBasicHttpBindingAuthentication();
   String authenticatedToken = "TOKEN";

   List<Handler> handlerChain = ((BindingProvider)basicHttpBindingAuthentication).getBinding().getHandlerChain();
   handlerChain.add(new SOAPHeaderHandler(authenticatedToken));
   ((BindingProvider)basicHttpBindingAuthentication).getBinding().setHandlerChain(handlerChain);

Comment: I have very similar objective to add the auth token to the SOAP header for OT connection. I have followed the same code but i am getting "SOAPFaultException: OTDS username and password are required." exception even though i have passed valid authenticated token. Could you please guide me where am i going wrong ? (i am able to connect with OT in a stand alone java app but not when i run as a webservice)

Comment: Try to see what you are sending as the SOAP envelop. You can do it by adding a handler. Follow the answer in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945618/tracing-xml-request-responses-with-jax-ws

Comment: By adding the handler, the complete SOAP envelope will be printed in the log, and you will see what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. I could figured out what is going wrong in the header with the link you have pointed out. Somehow the element was not getting added to the SOAP header. Thanks

Comment: Actually I had the same problem. That's why I sent this tip ! :-)

Comment: Wow man, exactly the same what I needed (I see you were also struggling with DocWeb CWS :-) :)

Comment: I had great help from this example! In my case, I had to replace `SOAPHeader header = envelope.addHeader()` with `SOAPHeader header = envelope.getHeader()` as my message already had a header and it is not possible to add several headers.

Answer (score 2):

i was facing the same issue and solved it by removing the xmlns:wsu attribute.Try not adding it in the usernameToken.Hope this solves your issue too.

Answer (score 0):

Maven dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.19</version>
    </dependency>
```

Configuration class

```
import org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor;

@Configuration
public class ConfigurationClass{

@Bean
public Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor() {
    Wss4jSecurityInterceptor wss4jSecurityInterceptor = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor();
    wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementActions("UsernameToken");
    wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementMustUnderstand(true);
    wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementPasswordType("PasswordText");
    wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementUsername("123456789011");
    wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementPassword("TestPass123");
    return wss4jSecurityInterceptor;
}
```

Result xml

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <wsse:Security
        xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
        xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
        SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-F57F40DC89CD6998E214700450735811">
            <wsse:Username>123456789011</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">TestPass123</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    ...
    something
    ...
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```