# Add SOAP Header to Java Webservice

Tags: java, eclipse

I have created and deploy a very simple test webservice on my server.

```
public class HelloWorld {

    @WebMethod()
    public String sayHello(String name) {
        System.out.println("Hello: " + name);
        return "Hello " + name + "!";
    }
}
```

next, i created a test client via File > New > Other > Web Services > Web Service Client.
Fill the wsdl address, and eclipse do generate several classes automatically:

```
- HelloWorld.java
- HelloWorldProxy.java
- HelloWorldService.java
- HelloWorldServiceLocator.java
- HelloWorldServiceSoapBindingStub.java
```

then code the test client:

```
HelloWorldProxy wsHelloProxy = new HelloWorldProxy();
String greeting = wsHelloProxy.sayHello('Jack');
System.out.println(greeting)
```

it is running succesfully.

My Question is, how can i add additional headers in my client code,
because i want to always send some information to my webservice.
May i get the example ?

Can anyone help?

thx

Comment: check if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976940/how-to-add-soap-header-in-java

Comment: thx, i've solve this problem