# Java : Where exactly the Properties would be configured?

Tags: java, tomcat, properties

Inside my Java class say Props.java File .
I have this static block as  shown

```
static
  {
    instanceName = System.getProperty("bayer.instanceName");
    systemPath = System.getProperty("bayer.home");
    if (systemPath == null)
      systemPath = ".";
    propsFile = new File(System.getProperty("bayer.home") + File.separator + "bayer.properties");
  }
```

Please tell me where this properties ,  bayer.instanceName and bayer.home would be defined ??
For more information i am using Apache Tomcat 6.0 server and Linux Environment .

Comment: Is this a duplicate of that one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445488/how-to-find-out-where-the-property-name-defined-inside-linux-machiene

Answer (score 2):

System properties are set on the java command line using the `-Dpropertyname=value` syntax, for example:

```
java -cp someclasspath -Dbayer.instanceName=foo com.mycompany.MyClass
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054972/java-system-properties-and-environment-variables/7054981#7054981) for more info.

Comment: I think `java -cp someclasspath -Dbayer.instanceName=foo com.mycompany.MyClass ` is correct. In your case `-Dbayer.instanceName=foo` will be considered as first system argument

Comment: Hi , from the link  I found out this useful ,  Environment variables are set in the OS, eg in linux export HOME=/Users/myusername or on windows SET WINDIR=C:\Windows etc.   But how can i see the properties file ??

Comment: @yyyi777 Your application must actively *load* a properties file - it's not automatic. Check the code to find out which files are being loaded

Answer (score 0):

Another standard location is

```
$TOMCAT_HOME/bin/setenv.sh
```

If you don't find them there do a  `grep bayer.home $TOMCAT_HOME/bin`

Another resource to check are the init-scripts which depend on your system. See `/etc/init.d`.