# How to find out where the Property name defined inside Linux Machiene?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, properties

I am using Linux machine, remotely through putty, for deploying our Java EE Application.
Inside the Tomcat server folder I need to find a property called `bayer.home`.

I have used the following command:

```
grep bayer.home /home/HHHuser/tomcat
```

to check if the property exists inside the Tomcat folder.

Please tell me is this correct or not?

If it's incorrect could anybody please tell me where the property names, say `bayer.home`, most probably would be defined?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "property"? The command you tried is working on the file system, and I assume, that you're looking for something in a Java namespace which is something entirely different.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you looking for a property defined in some `*.properties` file which is within `/home/HHHuser/tomcat`?

Answer (score 0):

grep 'bayer.home' /home/HHHuser/tomcat -rI