# getting environment variable's value in java?

Tags: java, jsp, operating-system

I have set an environment variable in windows by name "sample". Can I get this environment variable's value using below code?

```
System.getProperty("sample");
```

in UAT environment I have LINUX OS. Can I set the same environment variable in LINUX OS and retrieve the same using `System.getProperty("sample")`?

I mean does `System.getProperty("sample");` retrieves irrespective of the operating system?

Also, I would like to get the environment variable's value in JSP.I know it is not recommended to keep logic in jsp but still, I need to use it. Can I use `System.getProperty("sample");` in jsp? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes this is irrespective of OS and you can use it in JSP.

Comment: Hi Satya, Thanks for your reply. which one is irrespective of OS> System.getenv() or System.getProperty()?  Thanks!

Comment: @user1016403 they **both** are. Java is meant to be completely OS-independent.

Answer (score 16):

Use [`System.getenv()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv%28java.lang.String%29) to retrieve environment variables, not [`System.getProperty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29). The latter is for (as the name implies) system properties.

What's the difference? [Java system properties and environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054972/java-system-properties-and-environment-variables)

---

If you need to access an environment variable in a JSP, you're doing something wrong. At the very least, use a servlet. More reading: [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for your reply. what is difference between system properties and environment variables? Thanks!