# How to access environment variables from JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

How can I access environment variables from a JSP page?   Does one of the implicit objects give access to them?   I couldn't find an example addressing this specific issue.  Ideally I'm looking for something like:

```html
<c:set var="where" value="${myEnvironment.machineName}">
```

Comment: How do you define these *environment variables*?

Comment: when you say environment. Do you mean the OS or the JVM ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463323/getting-environment-variables-value-in-java)

Comment: Either an **environment variable** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable  or a **system property** http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html   Does that help?   And yes I know that **environment variables** and **system properties** are different, I'm just looking for some way to reach outside the JSP page and look at them.

Comment: @suninsky - no this is **not** a duplicate.

Comment: @user3120173 What are you looking for? What do you mean by `machineName` here? Are you talking about client machine name or server machine name?

Comment: My initial post was designed to be as brief as possible, however I've now concluded that was a terrible mistake.   I was not looking for information on Core JSTL, the <c:set> tag, or whether I could put something in the value="whatever" field.   I simply wanted to know if I could access environment variables from any of the implicit JSP/JSTL objects (pageContext, application, etc.)   Apparently my question was so short and poorly worded that it mystified everyone for which I apologize to you personally and everyone in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can read the properties file at the server start-up using [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) and store it as **application** scoped attribute to access it from anywhere in the application.

Steps to follow:

.properties:

```
machineName=xyz
```

web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.x.y.z.AppServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

AppServletContextListener.java:

```
public class AppServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    private static Properties properties = new Properties();

    static {
        // load properties file
        try {
            // absolute path on server outside the war 
            // where properties files are stored

            String absolutePath = ..; 
            File file = new File(absolutePath);
            properties.load(new FileInputStream(file));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        servletContextEvent.getServletContext().
                                    setAttribute("myEnvironment", properties);
    }
}
```

JSP:

Then you can just treat it as Map in EL.

```
${myEnvironment['machineName']}
```

or

```
${myEnvironment.machineName}
```

---

Read more about **JSTL Core `c:set` Tag**

The `<c:set>` tag is JSTL-friendly version of the `setProperty` action. The tag is helpful because it evaluates an expression and uses the results to set a value of a `JavaBean` or a `java.util.Map` object.

The `<c:set>` tag has following attributes:

[image]

If target is specified, property must also be specified.

Read more about it [HERE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_set_tag.htm)

---

If you are looking for sample code then find it here. Please find it at below posts. It might help you.

- [Acces value between two jsp with jstl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546238/acces-value-between-two-jsp-with-jstl?answertab=votes#tab-top)
- [JSP - Standard Tag Library (JSTL) Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm)

---

More samples on other scopes.

```
    <%-- Set scoped variables --%>
    <c:set var="para" value="${41+1}" scope="page" />
    <c:set var="para" value="${41+1}" scope="request" />
    <c:set var="para" value="${41+1}" scope="session" />
    <c:set var="para" value="${41+1}" scope="application" />

    <%-- Print the values --%>
    <c:out value="${pageScope.para}" />
    <c:out value="${requestScope.para}" />
    <c:out value="${sessionScope.para}" />
    <c:out value="${applicationScope.para}" />
```

*In your case you have set an attribute `where` in default `page` scope.*

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, which seems to be can you put an environment variable in the value="" clause? I get the impression from the above that the answer is no, but it never answers the question directly.

Comment: @developerwjk Yes I am just updating my post.