# Convert scriptlet into JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I have this code and I have read somewhere nowadays scriplets are highly deprecated and discouraged. I'd like to use JSTL for the following code but I have some issues to understand how JSTL and EL work. Do you have any suggestion, guides, how-to?

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*, ejb.EsempioEntity" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<%
    List<EsempioEntity> list = (List<EsempioEntity>)request.getAttribute("list");
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>View</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            if(list!=null)
            {
                for(EsempioEntity ee:list)
                {
                    out.print("<p>"+ee.toString()+"</p>");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                out.print("<p>Nessun dato!</p>");
            }
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Click on the JSTL tag at the bottom of your question. Then click the *info* tab. Same for EL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at below JSTL.

- [JSTL Core c:forEach, c:forTokens Tag](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_foreach_tag.htm)
- [JSTL Core c:if Tag](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_if_tag.htm)
- [JSTL Core c:choose Tag JSTL Core c:when Tag JSTL Core c:otherwise Tag](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_choose_tag.htm)

Sample code:

```
<c:if test="${list!=null }">
    <c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
        <p>${item}</p>
    </c:forEach>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${list==null }">
    <p>Nessun dato!</p>
</c:if>
```

OR try

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${list!=null }">
        <c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
             <p>${item}</p>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <p>Nessun dato!</p>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: Have a look at [How to access environment variables from JSP page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23704812/how-to-access-environment-variables-from-jsp-page/23705004#23705004) for more info about the scope.

Answer (score 1):

The core of it is going to look something like this:

```
<c:if test="${empty list}">
  <p>Nessum dato!</p>
</c:if>

<c:forEach items="${list}" var="row">
  <p><c:out value="${row}" /></p>
</c:forEach>
```

I recommend the resources found in the [JSTL info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) for additional information.