# Access spring environment aware variable in jsp

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

My environment variables are managed via spring profile and i have an xml that contains the entry below...

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/properties/app_config_${spring.profiles.active:dev}.properties" />
```

In the file app_config_dev.properties file, i have the entry below:
otherApp.baseurl=devEnvt.mainApp.com.au

In the backend, i have a Service object and the variable is annotated by @Value to take advantage of spring taking care of getting the value via the property file in which the application is deployed in (can be dev, staging or prod).

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class AppService {

   @Value("${otherApp.baseurl:https://test..}")
   private String baseUrl;
}
```

In the front end, i have this index.jsp that basically just redirects to a url.

```
<%

Account acc = Account.getAccount(session);
String url = request.getScheme() + "://" + "url_value_from_environment_aware_property_file" + "/reset";//url_value_from_environment_aware_property_file should be equal to otherApp.baseurl

if (acc != null){
   JSPUtil.contentInclude(pageContext, "error_loggedin.jsp");
}else{
   response.sendRedirect(url);
}

%>
```

My question is, given that I have a very basic jsp here, how can I access the environment aware variable that is being managed by Spring?

Answer (score 0):

We use `ServletContextListener` to load the properties file at the server startup as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23704812/how-to-access-environment-variables-from-jsp-page).

We have defined the context-param to activate the profiles for a web application.

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
   <param-value>web,jpa</param-value>
</context-param>
```