# Django : Writing a query with condition referencing aggregation within same table

Tags: python, sql, django

I have a table similar to this:

```
id  name   added     count  flag
---------------------------------
01  abcd1  09.02.13    4    false
02  abcd1  10.02.13    1    true  
03  abcd1  11.02.13    3    false
04  abcd1  12.02.13    4    false
```

I need to find sum of count for a given name with the following conditions:

- For a given name
- Flag should be false
- Entry should be added after the last flag=true entry for that name

In this case I want sum of count for entries 03 and 04.

How should I do this in Django?

**EDIT**:
I am looking for creating a query like this:

```
SELECT id from sample
WHERE 
  name = 'abcd1' AND
  added > (SELECT MAX(added) FROM sample WHERE name = 'abcd1' AND flag = TRUE)
```

**EDIT**:
Also if there was no entry with flag=true then I need all the entries for that name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly straightforward if you use a little subquery:

```
select
    name,
    sum(count)
from sample s
where flag = false
and (added > (select max(added)
    from sample
    where name = 'abcd1'
    and flag = true)
    OR
    not exists (
        select *
        from sample
        where name = 'abcd1'
        and flag = true)
    )
and name = 'abcd1'
```

Note the use of the `OR not exists` clause to handle the case when there are no entries with `flag=true`.

Comment: Do you know how to translate this into Django query?

Comment: Sorry, I am unfamiliar with django. Perhaps try a django forum.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for confirming the SQL query.

Comment: How do you handle the situation if there is no entry with flag=true? I still need the sum but now I need for all flag=false entries for a given name. SQL is fine if you could help me. Thanks.

Comment: For going "above and beyond", would you Ming up-voting both my answer *and* the accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054972). Thx :)

Comment: Sure :) I realized my question was not complete when I did some testing, so I have edited the question as well.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
select name, sum(count) as count
from T as t
where flag = 'false'
and exists (
    select 1
from T
where name = t.name
and flag = 'true'
group by name, flag
having max(added) < t.added
)
group by name
```

Comment: Performance is a function of implementation. Good query optimizers "flatten" the query, treat it more or less like a join. Expressing the query as simply as possible gives both man and machine the best opportunity of understanding it.

Comment: When exist condition is checked, does the sub-query within 'exists' run for every row? Or the query optimizer only executes it once? I just need to understand how it works. Thanks!

Comment: Many people think so, but the answer is No.  There's no rule about *how* the DBMS executes the query.  There are ways of thinking about it, and of course particular implementations have specific behavior.  To answer your question for your DBMS, the best answer is RTFM.  :-)