# On a windows Jenkins slave, how can I solve "No plugin found for prefix 'http' in the current project and in the plugin groups"?

Tags: windows, maven, jenkins

Starting yesterday, my build started o broke due to that exteremely weird error.

It happens when I launch one particular build using that particular jenkins slave.

When I launch that very build directly on that machine (that's to say using maven directly) it works without any trouble.

When i launch an other build on this slave through Jenkins, it also work correctly.

For the record, I've launched the build using the -X flag to have a better idea of what happen, and here is a part of the log being written

```
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Documents and Settings\ndx\.m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Documents and Settings\ndx\.m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for http://evgeny-goldin.org/artifactory/repo/
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/flexgroup/
Downloading: http://evgeny-goldin.org/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for http://nexus.server.name.hidden:8080/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/flexgroup/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://nexus.server.name.hidden:8080/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file C:\Documents and Settings\ndx\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\resolver-status.properties
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for http://nexus.server.name.hidden:8080/nexus/content/repositories/releases
Downloading: http://nexus.server.name.hidden:8080/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file C:\Documents and Settings\ndx\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\resolver-status.properties
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file C:\Documents and Settings\ndx\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\resolver-status.properties
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for http://nexus.server.name.hidden:8080/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots
Downloading: http://nexus.server.name.hidden:8080/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://nexus.server.name.hidden:8080/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (225 B at 3.5 KB/sec)
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file C:\Documents and Settings\ndx\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\resolver-status.properties
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/flexgroup/
Downloading: http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/flexgroup/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (13 KB at 200.4 KB/sec)
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file C:\Documents and Settings\ndx\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\resolver-status.properties
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for http://nexus.server.name.hidden:8080/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/
Downloading: http://nexus.server.name.hidden:8080/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file C:\Documents and Settings\ndx\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\mojo\resolver-status.properties
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for http://evgeny-goldin.org/artifactory/repo/
Downloading: http://evgeny-goldin.org/artifactory/repo/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file C:\Documents and Settings\ndx\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\mojo\resolver-status.properties
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/flexgroup/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (228 B at 0.5 KB/sec)
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file C:\Documents and Settings\ndx\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\resolver-status.properties
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for http://nexus.server.name.hidden:8080/nexus/content/repositories/releases
Downloading: http://nexus.server.name.hidden:8080/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file C:\Documents and Settings\ndx\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\mojo\resolver-status.properties
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for http://nexus.server.name.hidden:8080/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots
Downloading: http://nexus.server.name.hidden:8080/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file C:\Documents and Settings\ndx\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\mojo\resolver-status.properties
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (22 KB at 463.4 KB/sec)
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file C:\Documents and Settings\ndx\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\mojo\resolver-status.properties
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file C:\Documents and Settings\ndx\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\mojo\resolver-status.properties
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file C:\Documents and Settings\ndx\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\resolver-status.properties
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file C:\Documents and Settings\ndx\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\mojo\resolver-status.properties
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml in 3rd-party-nexys (http://nexus.server.name.hidden:8080/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/)
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml in evgenygoldin (http://evgeny-goldin.org/artifactory/repo/)
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml in sonatype-oss (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/)
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml in nexus-releases (http://nexus.server.name.hidden:8080/nexus/content/repositories/releases)
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml in sonatype-flexmojos (http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/flexgroup/)
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml in 3rd-party-nexys (http://nexus.server.name.hidden:8080/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/)
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml in evgenygoldin (http://evgeny-goldin.org/artifactory/repo/)
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml in sonatype-oss (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/)
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml in nexus-releases (http://nexus.server.name.hidden:8080/nexus/content/repositories/releases)
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml in nexus-snapshots (http://nexus.server.name.hidden:8080/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots)
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Documents and Settings\ndx\.m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote update check for org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml, already updated during this session.
[DEBUG] Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml in http://nexus.server.name.hidden:8080/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of 3rd-party-nexys has elapsed or updates are forced
[DEBUG] Skipped remote update check for org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml, already updated during this session.
[DEBUG] Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml in http://evgeny-goldin.org/artifactory/repo/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of evgenygoldin has elapsed or updates are forced
[DEBUG] Skipped remote update check for org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml, already updated during this session.
[DEBUG] Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml in https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of sonatype-oss has elapsed or updates are forced
[DEBUG] Skipped remote update check for org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml, already updated during this session.
[DEBUG] Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml in http://nexus.server.name.hidden:8080/nexus/content/repositories/releases was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus-releases has elapsed or updates are forced
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Documents and Settings\ndx\.m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote update check for org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml, already updated during this session.
[DEBUG] Failure to find org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml in http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/flexgroup/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of sonatype-flexmojos has elapsed or updates are forced
[DEBUG] Skipped remote update check for org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml, already updated during this session.
[DEBUG] Failure to find org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml in http://nexus.server.name.hidden:8080/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of 3rd-party-nexys has elapsed or updates are forced
[DEBUG] Skipped remote update check for org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml, already updated during this session.
[DEBUG] Failure to find org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml in http://evgeny-goldin.org/artifactory/repo/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of evgenygoldin has elapsed or updates are forced
[DEBUG] Skipped remote update check for org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml, already updated during this session.
[DEBUG] Failure to find org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml in https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of sonatype-oss has elapsed or updates are forced
[DEBUG] Skipped remote update check for org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml, already updated during this session.
[DEBUG] Failure to find org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml in http://nexus.server.name.hidden:8080/nexus/content/repositories/releases was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus-releases has elapsed or updates are forced
[DEBUG] Skipped remote update check for org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml, already updated during this session.
[DEBUG] Failure to find org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml in http://nexus.server.name.hidden:8080/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus-snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] project.name.hidden .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] project.name.hidden .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] project.name.hidden .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] project.name.hidden .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] project.name.hidden .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] project.name.hidden .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] project.name.hidden .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] project.name.hidden .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] project.name.hidden .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] project.name.hidden .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] project.name.hidden .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] project.name.hidden .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] project.name.hidden .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] project.name.hidden .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] project.name.hidden .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.703s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jan 16 09:11:56 CET 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/52M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'http' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Documents and Settings\ndx\.m2\repository), sonatype-flexmojos (http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/flexgroup/), 3rd-party-nexys (http://nexus.server.name.hidden:8080/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/), evgenygoldin (http://evgeny-goldin.org/artifactory/repo/), sonatype-oss (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/), nexus-releases (http://nexus.server.name.hidden:8080/nexus/content/repositories/releases), nexus-snapshots (http://nexus.server.name.hidden:8080/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.NoPluginFoundForPrefixException: No plugin found for prefix 'http' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Documents and Settings\ndx\.m2\repository), sonatype-flexmojos (http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/flexgroup/), 3rd-party-nexys (http://nexus.server.name.hidden:8080/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/), evgenygoldin (http://evgeny-goldin.org/artifactory/repo/), sonatype-oss (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/), nexus-releases (http://nexus.server.name.hidden:8080/nexus/content/repositories/releases), nexus-snapshots (http://nexus.server.name.hidden:8080/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:94)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.findPluginForPrefix(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:262)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:222)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:98)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
Build step 'Invoquer les cibles Maven de haut niveau' marked build as failure
```

I'm specially baffled by the last stack trace

```
org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.NoPluginFoundForPrefixException: No plugin found for prefix 'http' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Documents and Settings\ndx\.m2\repository), sonatype-flexmojos (http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/flexgroup/), 3rd-party-nexys (http://nexus.server.name.hidden:8080/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/), evgenygoldin (http://evgeny-goldin.org/artifactory/repo/), sonatype-oss (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/), nexus-releases (http://nexus.server.name.hidden:8080/nexus/content/repositories/releases), nexus-snapshots (http://nexus.server.name.hidden:8080/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:94)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.findPluginForPrefix(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:262)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:222)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:98)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

As I don't run any "http" prefixed command : the mvn command being send to slave is `mvn.bat -Dos=windows -DSVN_REVISION=7436 -Dsdk=indesign-sdk -DSVN_URL=http://svn.branc.name.hidden "-Dintegration=jenkins -Djava.awt.headless=true" clean deploy -pl :project.name.hidden -am -U -X`

**EDIT 1** I've finally gave up simple documentation reading and jumped the direct code analysis bandwagon. That bandwagon led me to run maven in remote debugging mode ([thanks to that article for the complete environment variable](http://netsuke.wordpress.com/2008/03/09/see-how-maven-works-inside-remote-debugging-plugins/)), which in turn led me to the method [`MojoDescriptorCreator#getMojoDescriptor`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.maven/maven-core/3.0.4/org/apache/maven/lifecycle/internal/MojoDescriptorCreator.java#MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor%28java.lang.String,org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession,org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject%29). An excerpt from maven 3.0.4 is copied below

```
public MojoDescriptor getMojoDescriptor( String task, MavenSession session, MavenProject project )
    throws PluginNotFoundException, PluginResolutionException, PluginDescriptorParsingException,
    MojoNotFoundException, NoPluginFoundForPrefixException, InvalidPluginDescriptorException,
    PluginVersionResolutionException
{
    String goal = null;

    Plugin plugin = null;

    StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer( task, ":" );

    int numTokens = tok.countTokens();

    if ( numTokens >= 4 )
    {
        // We have everything that we need
        //
        // org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.0:process
        //
        // groupId
        // artifactId
        // version
        // goal
        //
        plugin = new Plugin();
        plugin.setGroupId( tok.nextToken() );
        plugin.setArtifactId( tok.nextToken() );
        plugin.setVersion( tok.nextToken() );
        goal = tok.nextToken();

        // This won't be valid, but it constructs something easy to read in the error message
        while ( tok.hasMoreTokens() )
        {
            goal += ":" + tok.nextToken();
        }
    }
    else if ( numTokens == 3 )
    {
        // We have everything that we need except the version
        //
        // org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-remote-resources-plugin:???:process
        //
        // groupId
        // artifactId
        // ???
        // goal
        //
        plugin = new Plugin();
        plugin.setGroupId( tok.nextToken() );
        plugin.setArtifactId( tok.nextToken() );
        goal = tok.nextToken();
    }
    else if ( numTokens <= 2 )
    {
        // We have a prefix and goal
        //
        // idea:idea
        //
        String prefix = tok.nextToken();

        if ( numTokens == 2 )
        {
            goal = tok.nextToken();
        }
        else
        {
            // goal was missing - pass through to MojoNotFoundException
            goal = "";
        }

        // This is the case where someone has executed a single goal from the command line
        // of the form:
        //
        // mvn remote-resources:process
        //
        // From the metadata stored on the server which has been created as part of a standard
        // Maven plugin deployment we will find the right PluginDescriptor from the remote
        // repository.

        plugin = findPluginForPrefix( prefix, session );
    }

    injectPluginDeclarationFromProject( plugin, project );

    // If there is no version to be found then we need to look in the repository metadata for
    // this plugin and see what's specified as the latest release.
    //
    if ( plugin.getVersion() == null )
    {
        resolvePluginVersion( plugin, session, project );
    }

    return pluginManager.getMojoDescriptor( plugin, goal, project.getRemotePluginRepositories(),
                                            session.getRepositorySession() );
}
```

According to debugger session, when this method gets called, numToken is 2, which lead me to line 222 where, as it is written, the following code is called

```
        plugin = findPluginForPrefix( prefix, session );
```

with `prefix` being `http` while goal (unused here) is `//svn.branc.name.hidden`. In other words, maven consider the `-DSVN_URL=http://svn.branc.name.hidden` command line argument as a goal call ... WHAT THE HELL ?

Let's go up a little.

First calss being called is `org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher` which main method is given the following arguments array (thanks to Eclipse debugger):

```
args    java.lang.String[19]  (id=6596) 
    [0] "-Dos" (id=6597)    
    [1] "windows" (id=6598) 
    [2] "-DSVN_REVISION" (id=6599)  
    [3] "7436" (id=6600)    
    [4] "-Dsdk" (id=6601)   
    [5] "indesign-sdk" (id=6602)    
    [6] "-DSVN_URL" (id=6610)   
    [7] "http://svn.branc.name.hidden" (id=6583)    
    [8] "-Djava.awt.headless" (id=6611) 
    [9] "true" (id=6612)    
    [10]    "-Dintegration" (id=6613)   
    [11]    "jenkins" (id=6614) 
    [12]    "clean" (id=6615)   
    [13]    "deploy" (id=6621)  
    [14]    "-pl" (id=6622) 
    [15]    ":project.name.hidden" (id=6623)    
    [16]    "-am" (id=6624) 
    [17]    "-U" (id=6625)  
    [18]    "-X" (id=6627)
```

So it seems the first call made by the JVM to maven JAR splits the various `-D`, which (according to [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7054981/15619)) are supposed to be set as system properties. I'm totally puzzled now. What can I do to fix that ?

**EDIT 2** The very command line used to start Java is (thanks to [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)) `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\bin\java.exe" -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Npackd\Maven-3.0.5\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\Npackd\Maven-3.0.5\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\Npackd\Maven-3.0.5" org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher  -Dos windows -DSVN_REVISION 7436 -Dsdk indesign-sdk -DSVN_URL http://achille.perigee.fr/svn16/autocat/autocat-java/branches/1.3.0 -Djava.awt.headless true -Dintegration jenkins clean deploy -pl :project.name.hidden -am -U -X` Wait, where are my `=`? Mmmh, i think I have a really good trail there !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this was in fact one of Jenkins/Windows most surprising mismatches.

well, in fact, it's more due to Windows cmd.exe bad behaviour ...

I solved this by changing the labels I had to use only one label, which kept the command line short enough to not have the `=` characters removed from it. More a workaround than a real solution, but, well, it worked.