# How to set a system property via envirnmoent variable?

Tags: java, gradle, jvm

I need to set a system property via environment variable a then get access it with `System.properties['propName']`. I tried several patterns:

```
SET org.gradle.project.systemProp.buildRate=10
SET org.gradle.project.buildRate=10
SET ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_buildRate=10
SET ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_systemProp.buildRate=10
```

but none of these worked. How to do that?

Comment: the only way i know is java -Dorg.gradle.project.systemProp.buildRate=%org.gradle.project.systemProp.buildRate% (Windows). Or set it manually from java code - see System.getenv()

Answer (score 0):

They are [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054972/java-system-properties-and-environment-variables) things, you can set an environment variable and read it using `System.getenv()` or set a system property and read it using `System.getProperties()`.