# Retrieving command line -D options in Java

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have `clean integration-test -DclassId=app`as a maven goal in a Jenkins Maven Job.

How can I retrieve this in Java using `System.getenv();`? When I do this I am only seeing null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For command line options you have to use [`System.getProperty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) instead of [`System.getenv()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv%28%29):

```
String id = System.getProperty("classId");
```

Find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054972/java-system-properties-and-environment-variables).