# Maven java.exec environment variable is picked up by maven, but not picked up by the class

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-plugin

I added this maven job.

```
exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.someclass.SomeClass" -DAPP_HOME="${DEV_ENV_LOC}"
```

What happens is, spring context is able to pickup the value of APP_HOME, but the java class System.getEnv("APP_HOME"), is not able to pick up the value.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For command line options you have to use [`System.getProperty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

```
String appHome = System.getProperty("APP_HOME");
```

Or pass `APP_HOME` variable as an environment variable with [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) and lookup it with [`System.getenv()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv(java.lang.String)):

```
String appHome = System.getenv("APP_HOME");
```

Find more details in difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054972/java-system-properties-and-environment-variables).

Comment: Yes, but I don't own the code. What can I use to set env var?