# How does maven know JAVA_HOME set as an environment variable inUbuntu

Tags: java, maven, environment-variables, ubuntu-14.04

When I type mvn --version in ubuntu from the terminal(ubuntu),I get the below output.

```
Warning: JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set.
Apache Maven 3.0.5
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_79, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-32-generic", arch: "amd64", family:     "unix"
```

When I did not set any JAVA_HOME environment variable , how is maven getting the java home installed path.Is it trying to find this path from the /usr/bin/java command which is installed in my system and if so why is it taking the path till jre.

P.S : Also I could not find any java path in any maven config.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As showed in the [`CLIReportingUtils.java`](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/master/maven-embedder/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/cli/CLIReportingUtils.java) (the maven class that retrieves the Java Home), the value comes from the following call :

```
System.getProperty( "java.home", "<unknown java home>" )
```

The `java.home` is for the JRE unlike the `JAVA_HOME` which is for the JDK.
So Maven is displaying the JRE home.

Comment: My question was how come maven is picking some java path as JAVA_HOME when I did not set any.This is for ubuntu.

Comment: System properties are for Java only. You don't set it on the OS. You can set it while running a command (-DpropertyName) : http://stackoverflow.com/a/7054981/644669

Comment: ok.Got that.But which java process is setting this system property and how is it able to get this path ?

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/System.java#System.initProperties%28java.util.Properties%29  Then, go to the java native implementation (in c). The java.home is communicated by the OS to Java when installed.

Answer (score 1):

I would say there is a difference between  `JAVA_HOME` environment variable and the output `Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre`.
The latter is just the output of the installation directory [see here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).

So maven will run Java in background and java knows where its installed.

Comment: yes.I meant maven was treating this java location as JAVA_HOME for itself and hence its printed in mvn --version.

Comment: as @Zakaria posted, Maven just reads the `java.home` Property, which is by default the install-directory. `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home"))` is always the installation directory, `System.out.println(System.getenv("JAVA_HOME"))` is the value of the environment variable

Comment: Thanks for that.Was confused in choosing your answer and zakaria's.Just went with zakaria's for the source code link.

Answer (score 0):

I think,I understand it now.In the maven script i.e (usr/share/maven/bin/mvn) they are trying to find the java installed using a variety of options.

So at one place they are doing the below

```
JAVACMD="`which java`"
```

And now in my system "which java" points to the below

```
java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

Hope this is how its getting the java path.

Comment: Sorry to insist but as I pointed it in my answer you can see in the maven source code that the maven command is calling the following instruction : `System.getProperty( "java.home", "<unknown java home>" )`