# Should I use a VM Argument or Environment Variable?

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a piece of Java code using Apache Spark to join two dataframes with a conditional that relies on a VM argument `-DearlyData=TRUE` for an `inner join`, and `-DearlyData=FALSE` for a `leftanti join` depending on whether the VM argument is set to `TRUE` or `FALSE` (Technically, if it is set to `TRUE` or any other value.)

This is a simplified version of my code:

``

```
String earlyData = System.getProperty(Constants.EARLY_DATA);
    if(earlyData.equalsIgnoreCase("TRUE")){
        log.trace("Running Early Data");        
        DataBo.processData(earlyDF.join(cassandraDF, 
                earlyDF.col(AA).equalTo(example.col(BB))
                    .and(earlyDF.col(CC).equalTo(example.col(DD))),"inner")
                        drop(Constants.AA, Constants.CC));
    }else{
        log.trace("Running Late Data");
            DataBo.processData(earlyDF.join(cassandraDF, 
                earlyDF.col(AA).equalTo(example.col(BB))
                    .and(earlyDF.col(CC).equalTo(example.col(DD))), "leftanti")
                        .drop(Constants.AA, Constants.CC));
```

``

My code works, but my question is this:

- Should I use an `Environment Variable` or a `VM Argument` for the String `earlyData`?
- Are there drawbacks or unforeseen complications of using one versus the other in a `conditional` like this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7054981/1490322

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054972/java-system-properties-and-environment-variables/7054981#7054981) by user [Jose Martinez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1490322/jose-martinez), a VM argument is correct for this use case.

To elaborate, I have a Cron that kicks off the `inner` join in the morning by having `-DearlyData=TRUE` to retrieve early data, and a Cron that utilizes the `leftanti` join in the evening by using `-DearlyData=FALSE` in the script for late data.