# How can I get Spring Boot to load the Java System.getenv() variables into the Environment object?

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot

Azure loads startup details into the System.getenv() properties.  I would like them to show up in the Environment variable from Spring.

How can I accomplish this?

As a side note, is there a way to add a system variable at startup (for testing?)

Comment: I am trying to understand your question. Are your properties in system environment variables?

Comment: They should show up in environment. If not , then they are not getting added.

Comment: Maybe due to security it’s not allowing azure to add properties to environment

Comment: Are you saying that they should automatically get loaded?

Comment: No I am not saying that, but if you believe you have added commands( to add it into environment) it should.

Comment: Let me tell you the different possibilities-     1. Either ur commands are wrong . So it is not getting added to environment. 2. Your command is right but you are adding it as a system property not a system environment variable(read up about it). 3.there is security issue. Which is blocking azure to add the environment variables.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054972/java-system-properties-and-environment-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual answer to this question is "nothing".  Spring boot automatically loads all the System.getenv() into the Environment variable at startup.

See:  [Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

And yes, I am a bit embarrassed.

Answer (score 1):

you can add all your properties to application.properties in Spring Boot. otherwise, you can add a Bean in your spring boot application class that reads from the system properties & loads them.

Comment: I understand how I CAN add properties.  I need to add System.getenv() properties.  How do I add the bean?

Comment: if you weren't in a spring boot situation, you would possibly add a separate config class and annotate it with \@configuration. in your class annotated with \@SpringBootApplication you can also do the whole \@Bean annotation & do what you need to do there.

Comment: That is a great idea.  Why would spring boot be a bottleneck?  Do you have some code?  I saw some yesterday here but the author deleted it!

Comment: i'm not saying it's a bottleneck at all. in spring boot by declaring a class a \@SpringBootApplication that means you can put \@Bean definitions in there. Otherwise, you'd have to do a separate class annotated with \@Configuration and do your bean definitions there. It's just a matter of how/where you declare your beans. You could also do a separate \@Configuration class with Spring Boot but that would be silly extra work as like I typed, you can do it straight up in the class annotated w\ \@SpringBootApplication