# Access files outside of Web Server

Tags: java, unix, tomcat, servlets

I am running Tomcat on a Unix server, how can I write a Servlet to read from files on the Unix server but not contained in the WebContent folder.

Comment: One approach is to define a system or environment variable(s) to point to the location of the file(s).  This allows local/dev/test/prod to use different locations.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054972/java-system-properties-and-environment-variables) might help.  Another approach is to have a properties file, such as application.properties, which contains all of the properties that might be different between environments.  Then just have a single system/environment variable which points to that properties file.

Comment: I have a path variable $file_name that points to the file, would this work? Would you know how to get the specific file back from System.getenv()? Thanks @AndrewS

Comment: Use $file_name in the shell script to define a system property:  `java ... -Dfile_name=$file_name ...`.  Then in the code: `String fileName = System.getProperty("file_name")`.