# How to set java.util.logging.config.file in AWS Lambda Function?

Tags: java, aws-lambda

How can you use a custom logging configuration in AWS Lambda?

Specifically, I don't want to use log4j or slf4j or ACL. I'm using java.util.logging.

I tried setting `java.util.logging.config.file` as an environment variable, but this didn't work as the framework expects a `-D` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` to pass the relevant system properties into the lambda function.
Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/envvars002.html.

> In many environments the command line is not readily accessible to
>   start the application with necessary command-line options. This often
>   arises with applications that use embedded VMs (meaning they use the
>   Java Native Interface (JNI) Invocation API to start the VM), or where
>   the startup is deeply nested in scripts. In these environments the
>   JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS environment variable can be useful to augment a
>   command line.

In the AWS Lambda Console you can set the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` as a env variable with values like `-Dfoo=bar` and then this will be available as System properties in your program.
Do take a look at difference between System Properties and Env Varibles.

[Java system properties and environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054972/java-system-properties-and-environment-variables)