# System.GetProperties doesn't return the real value in Mac OS

Tags: java, bash, macos, kotlin, environment-variables

I am using the below line to read an environment variable from my Kotlin code.

```
val accountPasswords = System.getProperty("AccountPasswords")
```

I have stored this environment variable in my Mac OS machine in ~/.bash_profile, in the below shown way.

```
export AccountPasswords=myPassword
```

When I print this accountPasswords variable I get {$AccountPasswords} instead of the real value. I went on to print the properties and below is how I get it.

```
key: AccountPasswords value: {$AccountPasswords}
```

How can I print the actual value? What am I doing wrong here? This works fine when I run it in a Linux machine. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think that you have export AccountPasswords={$AccountPasswords}

Comment: probably, you're confused by `System.getProperties()` and `System.getenv()` methods. [Java system properties and environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054972/java-system-properties-and-environment-variables)

Comment: @SergeyLagutin But System.getProperties seem to work fine in fetching Linux env variables? :(

Comment: @Antoniossss no I have the real value. The export statement I have put in the question is the exact same thing from my bash profile

Comment: @SergeyLagutin but then why do he get ANY value?

Comment: @Antoniossss interesting question. probably he overrides the property in other places

Comment: @SergeyLagutin Then that would be the reason, not using "wrong set" i think.

Comment: Besides, if you quick test like   `System.getProperties().entrySet().forEach(e -> {
   System.out.println(e.getKey() + " -> " + e.getValue());
  })` You will se it contains envs as well (as default values). At least prints every env on my side.