# How to set Environment variable option while running JAR?

Tags: java, command-line, jar

I have a `JAR` which accepts environment variable options. When I run the main class manually by setting run configuration, I provide environment variable as : `KERBOROS_KEYTAB_LOC="location of the keytab file"`

Now I need to set these options while running the `JAR`. How I can set that? I tried below option but it is not working.

```
java -DKERBOROS_KEYTAB_LOC="location of the keytab file" -jar jarfile.jar
```

Comment: FYI, `-D` sets a Java _system property_, not an environment variable. These are different and separate mechanisms that can be used for roughly similar purposes.

Answer (score 11):

On linux, execute

```
$ export KERBOROS_KEYTAB_LOC="location of the keytab file"
```

On windows

```
C:\>SomeDir>set KERBOROS_KEYTAB_LOC="location of the keytab file"
```

then run the jar as always

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what value you would like to pass as part of environment variable.

If its just `key=value`pair where value is not `location path`, then you just use `-D`option , just like how you do `VM Args` and run.

I had to pass **`EPAAS_ENV=e1`** in environment variable and used below cmd

```
Java -DEPAAS_ENV=e1 -D<VM ARGS1> -D<VM ARGS2> -D<VM ARGS3> -jar <jarFile.jar>
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

In general, You can pass the enviroment variable like below while running a jar file.

example:

java -Djava.security.auth.login.config="/path/kafkalogin.config" -jar myApplication.jar

Comment: using `-Dkey...`, is not for setting environment variables, but would set a java system property. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054972/java-system-properties-and-environment-variables