# Is it possible to use the $SYSTEM prefix in the <args> section of payloadFactory mediator?

Tags: wso2, environment-variables, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I use WSO2 EI v6.5.0. I want to load username and password of an external SOAP service from the system environment variables into a payloadFactory mediator.  Is it possible to use the $SYSTEM prefix in the  section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script mediator works in my case:

```
<script description="get cereditorials" language="js">
<![CDATA[mc.setProperty("user", java.lang.System.getenv("ENV_USER"));
         mc.setProperty("pwrd", java.lang.System.getenv("ENV_PWRD"));]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The $SYSTEM prefix is not supported yet. But you can use the following syntax to get system variables.

`get-property('system', 'hello')`

Comment: Thank you! 
I have tried this:
`property name="UserName" expression="get-property('system', 'USERNAME')" `
But UserName is empty as a result.
[This article](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Accessing+Properties+with+XPath#AccessingPropertieswithXPath-systemscope) says that I can retrieve Java System properties using the 'system'.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054972/java-system-properties-and-environment-variables) says that System properties and Environment variables are quite different.
It looks like 'get-property' is not fit to get environment variables.