# Extract xml request file through stub in web-services

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I am using wsdl to invoke a web-service.
I wants to extract xml request file through the stub which I use.
So can anyone help me out with this...?

I have searched online at so many places but I don't find anything anywhere.

Please friends help me out with this issue.

Thank You very much.

Comment: > I wants to extract xml request file through the stub which I use  .. what do you mean by that

Comment: I am using stub to invoke a web-service. & I am passing it a object to invoke this service. & this method will send a request xml created from this object information to It's server. I want this request xml.

Comment: I think this already has been answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945618/tracing-xml-request-responses-with-jax-ws