# SOAP Debug message not getting printed

Tags: web-services, soap, jax-ws

I set -Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true in my client VM arguments.  I am using JAX-WS client.  But inspite of that SOAP Message is not getting printed in the console.  Any reason?

This is my client code.

```
package com.helloworld.client;

import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
import com.helloworld.ws.HelloWorld;

public class HelloWorldClient{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:9999/ws/hello?wsdl");

        //1st argument service URI, refer to wsdl document above
    //2nd argument is service name, refer to wsdl document above
        QName qname = new QName("http://ws.helloworld.com/", "HelloWorldImplService");

        Service service = Service.create(url, qname);

        HelloWorld hello = service.getPort(HelloWorld.class);

        System.out.println(hello.getHelloWorldAsString("Test String"));

    }

}
```

My server is I published using Endpoint.publish and is running locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on Server

```
com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump=true
```

You can also use `@HandlerChain(file = "....")` annotation 
More about Jax-WS Handlers [here](http://jax-ws.java.net/articles/handlers_introduction.html) and [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/amsurana/entry/jax_ws_handlers_part_3_of_3?lang=en)

Comment: I also took help of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945618/tracing-xml-request-responses-with-jax-ws.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct VM argument -Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true. Are you using any IDEA?