# Writing SOAP request/responses to a log file

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws, wss4j

I have a web service Client class that establishes a connection with the destination server using the wsdl url. This class uses JaxWsProxyFactoryBean and the WSS4JOutInterceptor to establish a secure connection. I would like to see the SOAP request generated by my code and response generated from the server.

I have tried including the following options when I run my jar from the command line

```
-Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true
-Dcom.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true
-Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump=true
-Dcom.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump=true
```

I am using log4j for logging and all the messages get written to a custom file. How can I dump the SOAP request/responses to this same file using command line options?

Do I have to make any code changes to the Client class to achieve this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945618/tracing-xml-request-responses-with-jax-ws

Comment: Yes, I checked that post first and tried Mr.Napik's answer. I am refraining from making a code change unless that's the only way to achieve this.

Comment: There's a JVM flag too. It's in the same question Ajay referenced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add the following lines to the class that creates a SOAP request:

```
LoggingInInterceptor loggingInInterceptor = new LoggingInInterceptor();
loggingInInterceptor.setPrettyLogging(true);
LoggingOutInterceptor loggingOutInterceptor = new LoggingOutInterceptor();
loggingOutInterceptor.setPrettyLogging(true);
factory.getInInterceptors().add(loggingInInterceptor);
factory.getOutInterceptors().add(loggingOutInterceptor);
```

I also had to update my cxf client to the latest version from Apache i.e. 2.7.12.
This printed out the SOAP headers to the console.