# Spring - Log payload of a JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring

I have the following definition (taken from http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#remoting-web-services-jaxws-access):

```
<bean id="accountWebService" class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean">
  <property name="serviceInterface" value="example.AccountService"/>
  <property name="wsdlDocumentUrl" value="http://localhost:8888/AccountServiceEndpoint?WSDL"/>
  <property name="namespaceUri" value="http://example/"/>
  <property name="serviceName" value="AccountService"/>
  <property name="portName" value="AccountServiceEndpointPort"/>
</bean>
```

How to add logging of the payload to see what I send and what I receive? The documentation is rather quiet on the topic of interceptors in the client.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945618/tracing-xml-request-responses-with-jax-ws and register that handler with the `JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean` using a `HandlerResolver` for which there is a property.

Comment: Hmmm, I was kind of hoping that it would be possible for one single bean, given I have dozen of beans like that and only want it logged for that one bean.

Comment: Herm you register it for a single bean... So not sure what isn't as expected... You configure the resolvers per web service...

Comment: @M.Deinum Well, the top answer is "use these global properties", which is not what I want. Do you mean the top answer, the accepted answer or another? Could you link to the answer itself rather than the question?

Comment: The accepted answer not the top answer.

Comment: @M.Deinum You might want to add this as an answer. If you do, I'll accept and validate it.