# JAXB client, Failed to read a response: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a webservice use jaxb, in client I build webservice client jar file by Netbean. My problem is sometime client send request but can't read response object, follow exception:

```
Failed to read a response: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,36959]
Message: Premature EOF]
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.soap.DeserializationException: Failed to read a response: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,36959]
Message: Premature EOF]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:113)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
```

Comment: The error is at line ... 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to intercept your XML requests and response as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945618/tracing-xml-request-responses-with-jax-ws)
You may solve your problem then.

Comment: Thank you! I hope this help ^^