# dumpTreshold not working

Tags: java, xml, soap, jax-ws

I use JAX-WS RI for SOAP XML exchanging with another service.
I am trying to see full error log of my soap xml sending, but can't do this because of truncating message:

```
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
    at org.apache.cxf.transpo

Message has been truncated

use com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dumpTreshold property to increase the amount of printed part of the message
--------------------
```

And I can't correct this using these settings:

```
System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true");
        System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true");
        System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump", "true");
        System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump", "true");
        System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dumpTreshold", "999999");
```

I mean dumpTreshold = 999999

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: As a suggestion only, you may consider setting this property on server startup command line just to make sure it is considered. Some properties may only be read on startup.

Comment: I use it on client, and it must apply the settings, but doesn't do it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've changed line

```
System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dumpTreshold", "999999");
```

with

```
System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dumpTreshold", "999999");
```

and now I can see full log.

Comment: I always add both package names as a matter of course.  Same goes for the other JAX-RS flags: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16338394/295797

Answer (score 1):

You can also set it in the environment.

For **jetty** I use:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS=" \
-Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true \
-Dcom.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dumpTreshold=999999 \ 
-Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dumpTreshold=999999"
```

Answer (score 0):

`HttpAdapter` class has:

```
static {
    ...
    try {
        dump_threshold = Integer.getInteger(HttpAdapter.class.getName() + ".dumpTreshold", 4096);
    } catch (SecurityException se) {
        if (LOGGER.isLoggable(Level.CONFIG)) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.CONFIG, "Cannot read ''{0}'' property, using defaults.",
                    new Object[] {HttpAdapter.class.getName() + ".dumpTreshold"});
        }
    }
    ...
```

and:

```
 pw.println(WsservletMessages.MESSAGE_TOO_LONG(HttpAdapter.class.getName() + ".dumpTreshold"));
```

Set parameter name depending on location of `HttpAdapter.class`.

Or just set both variations (Sun internal RI WS is repackaged with adding intermediate package level `.internal.`):

```
java ... \
-Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dumpTreshold=99999 \
-Dcom.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dumpTreshold=99999 \
```

Default is:

```
public static volatile int dump_threshold = 4096;
```