# Which tool can be help us to detect a software change automatically?

Tags: validation, selenium, continuous-integration, automated-tests, performance-testing

We should want to detect a software change in order to understand if a set of automated scripts (used for performance and functional testing) need an update.

Even better if it was possible to add this detection system in a Continous Integration process easily.

Our application is a single page desktop browser webapp, more or less the idea is:

- To create some Selenium scripts for a set of "happy-paths" of the main business flows of the application.
- For each user interaction simulated in the Selenium script, we want to record the server HTTP traffic from the Presentation Layer to the Business Layer (they communicate by using SOAP XML).

After that, we need some tool for validating the HTTP traffic from the Presentation Layer to the Business Layer for each "happy-path" recorded.

In particular **we want to detect if the HTTP traffic from the Presentation Layer and the Business Layer is *equivalent* to the HTTP traffic recorded previously** (mostly the number and the content of the HTTP requests). This for each automated user operation simulated with Selenium.

Could you suggest us some existing tool for that?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. We need to record the HTTP traffic from the server Presentation Layer to the server Business Layer because the HTTP traffic from the web clients of our application uses a special encrypted encoding. The Presentation Layer communicates with the Business Layer by using SOAP XML, easy to record and to validate.

Comment: You're looking for a [Test Impact Analysis](https://martinfowler.com/articles/rise-test-impact-analysis.html) tool. There's no one tool that fits all solutions so it depends on the language you're using. The second request sounds like [IP traffic inspection](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/5958481/). It's possible you're referring to [packet inspection](https://github.com/suriyadeepan/NetCla). As for the logging of SOAP XML, there's probably a number of options like [jax-ws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945618/tracing-xml-request-responses-with-jax-ws).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will check your links.