# Adding logging to soap web service

Tags: soap, groovy, wsdl, wsdl2java, javax.xml

I would like to log my request and response.
I found a very easy solution to do so by changing the properties recommended here:
[Tracing XML request/responses with JAX-WS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945618/tracing-xml-request-responses-with-jax-ws?answertab=votes#tab-top)

My problem is, that I do not want to log credentials, so I manually need to adapt the log-message.

I am new to soap so I have not much experience at all.

I use a gradle plugin to create java classes of my WSDL: https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/no.nils.wsdl2java

My code to create a service:

```
import javax.xml.namespace.QName
import javax.xml.ws.Service
[...]

private MYSoapWsdlClass createClient(String url) {

    URL serverEndpoint = new URL(url)
    QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName("DOC_URL", "SERVICE_NAME")
    Service service = Service.create(serverEndpoint, SERVICE_NAME)
    return service.getPort(MYSoapWsdlClass.class)
}
```

So how could I get the logging handler in here?
Or is there another easy way to instantiate my service using the wsdl?
Usually I use groovy, but could not find a `wsdl2groovy` plugin.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We now use `org.apache.cxf`

It was a bit tricky to figure it out at first, but then it does provide a very nice way to add features - including a logging feature.

The Service is created int he spring config:

```
  public static final LoggingFeature LOGGING_FEATURE = new LoggingFeature(outSender: new CustomEventOutSender(),
                                                                      inSender: new CustomEventInSender(),
                                                                      limit: -1)

@Bean
MYSoapWsdlClass mYSoapWsdlClass() {
    JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean(serviceClass: MYSoapWsdlClass.class,
                                                          address: url,
                                                          features: [LOGGING_FEATURE]
    )
    return factory.create()
}
```