# Find exact soap request and response xml created

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

How can I find the exact soap request and response generated.
Here is the sample code I am using:

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "", name = "")
@XmlSeeAlso({ObjectFactory.class})
public interface ServiceSoap {

    @WebMethod(action = "")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "", targetNamespace = "", className = "")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "", targetNamespace = "", className = "")
    @WebResult(name = "", targetNamespace = "")

    public ResponseType sampleRequest(@WebParam(name = "", targetNamespace = "")java.lang.String str);

    }
```

This is invoked by the following code snippet

```
ResponseType response = serviceSoap.sampleRequest(str);
```

I want to find what is the exact soap request/response generated.

Comment: Have a look at [Tracing XML request/responses with JAX-WS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945618/tracing-xml-request-responses-with-jax-ws).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Apache CXF you can use the classes `LoggingOutInterceptor` and `LoggingInInterceptor`:

```java
StringWriter soapMessageWriter=new StringWriter();
LoggingOutInterceptor loi=new LoggingOutInterceptor(new PrintWriter(soapMessageWriter));
loi.setPrettyLogging(true);
ClientProxy.getClient(serviceSoap).getOutInterceptors().add(loi);
LoggingInInterceptor lii=new LoggingInInterceptor(new PrintWriter(soapMessageWriter));
lii.setPrettyLogging(true);
ClientProxy.getClient(serviceSoap).getInInterceptors().add(lii);


//do your stuff

String soapContent=soapMessageWriter.getString();
```

Comment: I want to fetch request and response as string rather than logging. Can you suggest for that?

Comment: Simply use a StringWriter. I changed the code accordingly.