# log SOAP messages in Guidewire Insurance Suite

Tags: java, logging, soap, guidewire

I want to catch the SOAP communication between my GW applications (Claim Center and Contact Manager). I'd like to make CC or CM write the requests and responses to the log file, or at least to see  them through debugger somehow. It seems to me that Guidewire's framework does not help regarding this.

I have tried [setting the system properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16338394/1506226) but it does not work, maybe the framework overrides them somehow. I have also tried to [define and utilize a SOAPHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1957777/1506226) but it works with a @WebService implementation, and my web service (Contact Manager's `ABContactAPI`) is defined in other way, using the framework.
Is there a way to fit Guidewire's web service into this scenario ? Or some other way to make Guidewire's web service log its SOAP messages somewhere ? Or to make Guidewire's web client code log its SOAP messages ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understand your case as you keep referring to the JAX-WS implementation and just to be clear Guidewire Soap framework does not use JAX-WS.

There is an "easy" way to log the whole SOAP envelop if you are using @WsiWebService Soap server or utilising the WebServiceCollections Soap client.
You have to simply register a transformer by attaching it to the web service server class like this:

```
@WsiRequestTransform(MySoapServer._loggingRequestTransformer)
```

You can do the same with the @WsiResponseTransform to catch the response.
The transformer is simply a block consuming and returning InputStream of type like:

```
block(InputStream) : InputStream
```

It's somewhat similar for the client. There you have to register a Configuration Provider in the "wsc" file. And then in the implementation of it you have access to the config object where in similar way you can register your request/response transformers.

```
config.RequestTransform = _logWebServicePayload
```

There are however few caveats to this approach.

- It will invoke the transformer for every single request/response while the transformer is registered so be 100% sure the transformer isn't logging your payload all the time esp. in Production! (only do any work there if for example the "_LOGGER.DebugEnabled")
- It requires you to return the InputStream and you most likely want to return the same information that you got in so extract it and wrap it again into some buffered InputStream or something similar
- Soap payloads sometimes contain sensitive data or PII data so be very careful what you do with those logs and that you have permission to dump such information into the logs. I typically register separate loggers and appenders for that so they can be dealt with proper care and additional infra setup

So please only do this if you really need to and ensure it does not run in PROD 100% of the time and that you have takes all the necessary actions.

Comment: I do not have info about implementation of GW web services, so I just tried with JAX-WS as probably most common solution.

Comment: That's OK, I was just not sure if you were after Guidewire solution (which you obviously were) or you want to implement it in some other conditions - all good and clear now!

Comment: For future reference, here's the product documentation link for the api calls above.  Note that the doc presents this in the context of security configuration but as Gwisard has documented this is a general purpose api.

https://docs.guidewire.com/cloud/pc/202310/integration/integration/topics/c_jt3699122.html?hl=requesttransform

Answer (score 1):

Using Gwisard's answer, I have implemented logging on server side :

```
/** Uncomment for debugging only! Do not push uncommented!

@WsiRequestTransform(\requestStream -> {
    var request = new String(requestStream.readAllBytes(), java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    logSOAPMessage(request, "INPUT")
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(request.getBytes())
})

@WsiResponseTransform(\responseStream -> {
  var response = new String(responseStream .readAllBytes(), java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
  logSOAPMessage(response, "OUTPUT")
  return new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBytes())
})*/
```

And the method which writes both request and response to log file:

```
  private static function logSOAPMessage(text : String, direction : String){
    var logFilePath = "C:\\tmp\\gwlogs\\soap.log"
    var logStream = new java.io.FileOutputStream(logFilePath, true)
    logStream.write("\n\n${java.time.LocalTime.now().format(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm.ss.SSS"))} ${direction} \n${text}".getBytes());
    logStream.close();
  }
```

Comment: and where do we need to keep this code?

Comment: Annotations should reside in the file where web service class is defined, above the class definition, together with other annotations.
I have put logSOAPMessage() into web service class, but you can put in which ever class you want, just make it public.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to log the actual SOAP envelop request/response for a function defined in a `@WsiWebService` class. You can always log the input of the function and then log the output of the function before the return. Something like:

```
public function mySoapFunction (accountNumber : String) : AccountDTO {

  //I assume a logger is defined for this web service class
  logger.info("Calling mySoapFunction with accountNumber ${accountNumber}")

  //The function implementation...

  logger.info("Returning from mySoapFunction with account ${accountDTO.toXml()}")
  return anAccountDTO
}
```

The above is just pseudo-code that I can't guarantee even compiles. The basic idea is you can do the logging yourself in the actual SOAP function. This is tedious, but I don't believe there is a way to log the SOAP request/responses natively in Guidewire applications by adjusting a setting.

Comment: The problem is that the generation of soap messages is somewhere deep inside Guidewire's framework and I am not allowed to access it.
What I see is the line
      var result = ContactAPI.searchContact(remoteCriteria, remoteSpec)
and the method searchContact() is inside Guidewire's jar and I cannot access its source code.
This call breaks with exception (after getting response from CM) and I cannot see any DTO object.

Comment: So what is the exception being thrown when `ContactAPI.searchContact` is called? Can you still log the `remoteCriteria` and `remoteSpec` variables?

Comment: It is some NullPointerException with a deep stack trace inside the framework. Obviously the framework gets the response from CM side (btw, on CM side, I see resulting object in debugger, and it looks just fine, but I cannot see how it gets serialized to xml response), and then after that. on CC side, the framework part which processes the response runs into null value where it should not.

Comment: Yeah this one will be hard to debug. My best guess at this point is that CM is returning some contact without a required field that ClaimCenter expects to be populated. I would do this: 1) use the CC Contact Search UI to find a search that consistently throws the exception and then 2) use SOAP-UI to call the CM web service directly (with the same search criteria) and see which contact result(s) are different and possible missing a required field. Tedious but that is where I would start

Answer (score 0):

On the client side, a snippet like this may be added to configuration manager class's `configure` method :

```
    config.RequestTransform = new gw.xml.ws.StreamTransform() {
  function transform(requestStream : java.io.InputStream) : java.io.InputStream {
    var request = new String(requestStream.readAllBytes(), java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    print(request)
    return new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(request.getBytes())
  }
}

config.ResponseTransform = new gw.xml.ws.StreamTransform() {
  function transform(responseStream : java.io.InputStream) : java.io.InputStream {
    var response = new String(responseStream.readAllBytes(), java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    // use this interception for something else, for example, alter the server response with other xml, for testing purposes
    var testingXML = LoadXMLFromFile(fileName)
    return new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(testingXML.getBytes())
  }
}
```